# Reloading all view controllers in a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have an iPad app with a UITabBarController with 7 view controllers.

This is in my applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [self createViewControllers];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

And this also in my appDelegate:

```
- (NSArray *)createViewControllers
{
    MyView1 *viewController1 = [[MyView1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView1" bundle:nil];
    MyView2 *viewController2 = [[MyView2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView2" bundle:nil];
    MyView3 *viewController3 = [[MyView3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView3" bundle:nil];
    MyView4 *viewController4 = [[MyView4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView4" bundle:nil];
    MyView5 *viewController5 = [[MyView5 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView5" bundle:nil];
    MyView6 *viewController6 = [[MyView6 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView6" bundle:nil];
    MyView7 *viewController7 = [[MyView7 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView7" bundle:nil];

    NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4, viewController5, viewController6, viewController7, nil];

    return views;
}
```

At any time, I want the user to be able to completely reload those view controllers, so any changes made, any animations in progress, any subviews etc, are flushed from memory and the view controllers are all loaded afresh.

I found the simplest way to do this is to add a shake gesture in the appDelegate. The shake gesture pops up a UIAlertView which asks "Do you want to reset everything?" If yes, this happens:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [self createViewControllers]; // <-- this happens

        // some of the other things I've tried
//        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:[self createViewControllers] animated:YES]; // same as above but with animation

//        self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; // allocations go crazy!
//        self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
//        self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [self createViewControllers];
//        self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    }
}
```

I replace the array of view controllers with a freshly created set. You can see a couple of the other things I've tried as well.

What I don't understand is why every time the reset is performed, the allocations in Instruments go up (and stay up) and the app starts to slow down. The more I reset, the more it slows down until it becomes unusable.

I'm using ARC and I would expect it to take care of the memory management each time I refresh the view controllers in the tab bar controller. Yet each refresh eats up more memory, no matter how I do it.

What could it be that is slowing everything down?

Comment: You did a great job in describing your problem, and your code is just perfect - the right coverage. This all looks just fine. While what you have here would appear perfect. I usually try to not perturb the UI in a delegate method. Try putting "        self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [self createViewControllers];" in a dispatch block on the main thread. If that does not do it will take a deeper look. What you are doing is perfectly reasonable (and I do something similar myself)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to read up more on blocks as I've hardly used them so far.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [self createViewControllers]; } ); - this is the form - you can re-use everything but the assign statement to do this in the future!

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I tried it but no difference. Unfortunately, I've run out of time to do further testing on this so it looks like I'll have to drop the feature from the app for now. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: A good trick to find leaking objects is to log when they get dealloc'd. So you log the object's class and some small piece of identifying information. When you do a big change, look at the logs for viewControllers that are not giving you this log message. NSTimers and other objects can retain the view controller and thus the leak.